# Handle hard bounces / complaints or just stick to suppression list?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

Email NOOB here. Planning to use Amazon SES for transaction email. Trying to understand how to handle emails that bounce or get marked as spam. SES automatically adds bounce/complaint recipients to the suppression list.

[What I read about suppression list:](https://sesblog.amazon.com/post/Tx2H36ZIFTEVXOZ/Goodbye-blacklist-Introducing-the-suppression-list)

> Suppression list is a list of recipient addresses that Amazon SES
>   blocks because the addresses have caused a hard bounce for any Amazon
>   SES sender within the past 14 days....If you try to send an email to an address on the suppression list, the call to Amazon SES succeeds, but Amazon SES treats the email as if it was a hard bounce.

Is there a benefit to setting up SNS + SQS to monitor complaints and bounces if I don't have a list of emails as [described here](https://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxJE1JNZ6T9JXK/Handling-Bounces-and-Complaints)

[image]

If an email is on suppression list, then the next time SES tries sending, the email will never get to ISP. So, the negative is that I pay for that email transaction.  What are the other negatives? What am I missing here?

**Clarification:** Totally understand why my question can rub people the wrong way. I'm not a marketer or spammer with a list of emails.  I have a service for which people sign up for.  The emails that can be mistyped - welcome email, reset a password, email document to someone else.  These actions require a user to type in emails.  If they mistyped or have a bad email address, the email will bounce or marked as spam. How do I handle it?  With a list, I can just remove that email from a list.  With transaction email, do I start keeping my own blacklist? Then check my blacklist before sending?

Answer (score 5):

This question leaves me with an impression that I, as a human with an e-mail address, find highly offensive.

It appears to be an attempt to justify a lack of willingness to be a responsible e-mail sender.

Hopefully, I have misinterpreted your motivation.

Consider this: SES does not allow you to take a path of least resistance, easily.  You **have to** accept the notifications, one way or another:

> You must receive bounce and complaint notifications either by email or through Amazon SNS
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications.html

This requirement should be sufficient to answer the question.  Maintain your own list of people you should not send mail to, ever again, and don't try to send to them.

But, there's more.  SES is a service for legitimate senders, and they are monitoring sender behavior.

> High bounce and complaint rates put your account at risk of being shut down, so you need to make sure that you have a process in place to remove recipient addresses that have bounced or complained from your recipient list.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/best-practices-bounces-complaints.html

So, apart from my own indignation, I believe the implications are clear -- SES expects you to manage your list and your bounces, properly.

The suppression list is not for convenience.  It is for the benefit of SES and its conscientious users, helping SES maintain a high reputation for only delivering mail people want, to people who want it, and thereby maintain high deliverability for legitimate mail by preventing the inevitable backlash from repeated bounces.

It's a safety net -- not a safety harness.

---

If you're sending only transactional emails, then your "list" -- assuming you don't already have some opt-in/validation records -- starts with the recipient of the first e-mail you send, and instead of being a list from which you remove people, is a list of people you've sent to, and whether it worked out or not.

It's more work up front, but you will hate yourself soon enough if you send automated emails without keeping track of what you sent and who you sent it to (and the associated SES message-id).

In case of a bounce or complaint, store the info and flag that address in your "list" so that you can avoid sending to it in the future.  Otherwise, store the delivery notification for your future reference.

Comment: Thank you for addressing these points. I understand the concern and I've updated my question with 'Clarification' section. tl;dr so how do people who send transaction emails handle bounces & complaints?  With a list, it's an easy "remove from list" answer but with transaction email?

Comment: Updated.  Maintain a local list of bounces and complaints.